# diff -s command says text files are identical when they are not, in zsh on macOS

Tags: zsh, macos, diff

I've observed unexpected behavior (that seems to be a bug) in diff in recent versions of zsh on macOS, the problem is specifically with the -s directive.  diff -s lists difference, but it *always* adds the line at the end that says the files are identical whether they are or not.  This did not used to be the case (some years ago); previously the line that the files are identical only appeared when diff had found no differences (as, I believe, is the expected behavior).

```
% diff file-one.txt file-two.txt 
1c1
< one
---
> two
% diff -s file-one.txt file-two.txt
1c1
< one
---
> two
Files file-one.txt and file-two.txt are identical
%
```

Comment: Is that all the content of the files? Can you reproduce this by running `printf 'one\n' >  file-one; printf 'two\n' > file-two; diff -s file-one file-two`? Also, the shell isn't relevant here, `diff` isn't a builtin, so this should be the same in all shells.

Comment: Can not reproduce this with `diff (GNU diffutils) 3.8`, what is your version of `diff`?

Comment: Yet another reason to avoid the s..t Apple dishes out (and has the audacity to call *open source*). Get tools that work using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) (or homebrew).

Comment: '''% diff --version
Apple diff (based on FreeBSD diff)
2023-12-05 18:02:56 ~ %

Comment: % printf 'one\n' >  file-one; printf 'two\n' > file-two; diff -s file-one file-two
1c1
< one
---
> two
Files file-one and file-two are identical
2023-12-05 18:11:29 ~ %